# How to let the user input text to search array object, then output if there is a match? Pure Javascript please

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I am new to javascript, so please bare with me.Everyone on this site is so amazing to us newbies so thank you in advance.So here is where I am... I am building a really generic music app(sorta). It wont be used in any real scenerio, it is simply to learn and understand js. So I am stuck in a couple places. I have a constructor for my array object, i push albums into the array then display them into a table that can be organized in different ways onclick of buttons. Now I am trying to have a search box that will take users input text, compare it to the array, then when there is a match displays in the output textarea(or whatever is best) I cant seem to get it to work, any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, should I have a window.onload event and put all my functions init?

To see everything I have together:
[here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kathleen1313/6s3q9/3/)

And here is the code i cant seem to get to work:

```
    //function to display artist info inner HTML if in array
    function displaySearchResult() {
    albums.sort(compareSearch);
    var output= document.getElementById("response");
    var formInput = document.getElementById("formInput").innerHTML;
      for (var i=0; i<album.length; i++){
           if (album[i].artist == formInput) {
       output = formInput + " , " + album[i].title + " " + album[i].artist;

   } else {
      alert("not found");
   }
   }
 }
```

The HTML:

```
    <input type="text" id="formInput" value="Search for an Artist"> </input> <br>
    <button id="search" >Submit</button>
    <p><textarea name="response" rows="0" cols="45" wrap></textarea></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few problems, it should be `artists` not `artist`, `output.value` not `output`, in html should be `id` not `name` for `textarea`, you need to `trim` the user input of whitespace, I removed the alert from inside the loop (very annoying). I'm sure there was some other things but forgotten now. I still see a number of areas where this can be improved but I have not done anything about them. Here is my update. (it's funny, much  of the code seems familiar somehow). Oh yes, be carefull when using `innerHTML` if you actually meant `textContent`, and when getting user input from an `input` element use `value`

http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/SSVSW/

Comment: Sorry it took a sec to get back. i hava a 5 year old..Sooo... Anyway. Thank you I have been tinkering from the awesome jumping off point you  gave and I realized I may be going about things the wrong way. Could I simply do a search with user input then loop through the table then display? or is this bad practice? Hey. pretty sure I told you last time... your awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Use `output.value` instead of `output` in assigning statement. like this

```
output.value = formInput + " , " + album[i].title + " " + album[i].artist;
```

Also if you are expecting to show multiple list then you have to concatenate the results .like this

```
var output= document.getElementById("response");
var formInput = document.getElementById("formInput").innerHTML;
output.value = "";
  for (var i=0; i<album.length; i++){
       if (album[i].artist == formInput) {
           output.value += formInput + " , " + album[i].title + " " + album[i].artist;

       } else {
           alert("not found");
       }
  }
```

Assign id value `"response"` to your `textarea` tag since you are using `getElementById`.

And  its better to have `window.onload` function for intialising  all your functions